# LIKE 'x%' works, but LIKE '%x' doesn't work on INT converted to STRING

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-like

I've found this strange behaviour and I searched but couldn't find anything about it.
I know that in my example I don't need to cast `[affairenum]` to `STRING`, but because of a specific syntax in Entity Framework this is how an `Affairenum.Contains()`, `StartsWith()` or `EndsWith()` ends up being generated.

Consider for example a table that contains an id (affaireid column) and numbers (affairenum column) with values from 1 to 5000000.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [affaireid]
      ,[affairenum]
      ,STR(affairenum) AS string
  FROM [dbo].[ULAffaire]
where STR(affairenum) LIKE N'%9'
```

Works and returns results. Same goes with `N'%9%'`.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [affaireid]
      ,[affairenum]
      ,STR(affairenum) AS string
  FROM [Ulysse].[dbo].[ULAffaire]
where STR(affairenum) LIKE N'9%'
```

Does not work and returns nothing. The difference here being `LIKE N'9%'`, the equivalent of a `StartsWith()`.

`STR(affairenum)` looks identical to `affairenum`, `EndsWith()` and `Contains()` both work normally, but this returns nothing.

I've tried with `LOWER()`, to no avail. Is the `STR()` method adding anything ? a space, some weird character ? Am I missing something silly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `str()` left pads the results with spaces.  The default is a length of 10 (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).

I'm not a fan of using numbers as strings.  But if you do so, explicit conversion should do what you want:

```
where cast(affairnum as varchar(255)) like '9%'
```

That is, `str()` is not a type conversion function.  It is a string formatting function -- hence the presence of spaces where you might not expect them.

I should note that you don't even need to explicit convert the number to a string, so this works:

```
where affairnum like '9%'
```

However, I have such bad memories of hours and hours devoted to fixing problems in SQL code that used implicit conversion, so I cannot in good conscience propose implicit conversion to someone else.

Comment: I knew it was something like that. Unfortunately I'm forced to cast to String because of some silly limitations of Linq-to-SQL, and while I can't do a cast() like you suggest, I can do a .Trim() to remove the whitespaces.